# How to make view "cache do" analog in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I want to wrap `cache` in my view:

```
- cache_wrap(cache_key, cache_options) do
  %div cached block
```

With cache_wrap like with:

```
helper_method :cache_wrap
def cache_wrap(key, options)
  if key.empty?
    yield
  else
    Rails.cache.fetch(key, options) do
      yield
    end
  end

  nil
end
```

And i want to have cache_wrap in controller, not in helper. Can i do this? 
I want to dispose cache_wrap logic in controller, because this logic related with another code that is living in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work as expected.

But probably, instead of putting `cache_wrap` into controller, you should expose your controller logic to the view layer, using the same `helper_method` hook.

This way you keep your controllers cleaner while still having the functionality as planned.